# How do I insert the value of my variable into my MySQL database?

Tags: python, mysql

Here's my variable "contents", which stores the text of "enty_12".

```
enty_12=tk.Text(root, height=10, width=70)
contents = enty_12.get('1.0','end')
```

I want to insert the value of "contents" into my MySQL database "pathology".

```
conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",username="root",password="root",database="pathology")
my_cursor=conn.cursor()
my_cursor.execute("insert into pathology values(%s)",(
                                         contents
                                         ))
```

But this doesn't work. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Include the **Column Name** in your MySQL query.

The query should be like

```
my_cursor.execute("insert into pathology (column_name) values(%s)",(contents,))
```

Replace the *'column_name'* with your actual *column name*.